# BitmapFactory.decodeStream returning null with bmOptions

Tags: android

Trying to get image from gallery, my photo uri : `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A15672`

when i don't use bmOptions(`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream))` i get bitmap image succesfully, but when i add bmOptions`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream,null,bmOptions))` i get `null` bitmap, unable to figure out what am doing wrong.

```
private void setPic(Uri photoUri) {

        InputStream inStream = null;
        try {
            inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        Log.i("response", "INPUT STREAM| Bitmap : "+ BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream,null,bmOptions));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior if you use `bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;`, which can be translated to human language as `don't load the bitmap, just resolve it's size and some other metadata`. It is usually used to know `Bitmap` size before loading it to memory to prevent `OOM` exceptions, and load bitmap pre-down-scaled.